# there are components such as infragistics or telerik for java or netbeans?

Tags: java, netbeans, telerik, components, infragistics

are there any components such as *infragistics* or *telerik* for **Java/Netbeans** ?

I couldn't find any info regarding this.

thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

have a look at [PrimeFaces](http://www.primefaces.org). These are some `JSF` Components and also usable on Mobiles.
If you want to have an Overview over all Components and what they can do have a look at the [Showcase](http://www.primefaces.org/showcase/ui/home.jsf).

Comment: I would like to know of some more